# Why local variable addresses are different by which program started it?

Tags: c, binary, exploit, ctf, pwntools

I ran into a confusion about memory address issue during my experiment to practice CTF pwn questions.

I tried to find the start pointer address of a local array variable to insert shellcode with Radare2. But the obtained pointer address was different when it was run from python to use pwntool.

---

This background context is a bit complex. I created a simpler reproducible code and here ere are my questions.

I compiled this following code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char buffer[300];
    printf("%x",buffer);
}
```

with this compile option.

```
gcc source.c -o vuln -fno-pie -no-pie -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32
```

When I run this program simply from my bash or Radare2, it will generate the address like `0xffffcb24`.

But when I use Python to run the built binary with this following python code, the address is different and it was `0xffffc9f4`.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("./vuln")
```

These experiments was on my Ubuntu environment with disabling ASLR.

I don't have any rational explanation on this difference. Could someone help me to understand these difference?

(Note: The address run from a different shell file was also different. I reckon this is not a Python specific problem)

Comment: `%p` is the correct `printf` format directive for printing a pointer value.  Technically, you should also cast the corresponding argument to type `void *`.  Making those corrections might or might not cause different output to be produced.

Comment: Also, the return type of `main()` is `int`.  It is at best non-standard to use `void`.

Comment: A different environment may launch the code in a different way, with a different "wrapper".

Comment: adding to that: the environment variables and arguments are stored on the stack, if this is Linux

Comment: My first guess as to an actual explanation for the reported differences would be that you are mistaken about ASLR being disabled, though I might revise that if printing the pointers correctly still showed their addresses being so close together.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Let me clarify a little bit.
I compiled the binary just one time. And binary was executed from the different way.
The output is always `0xffffcb24` when I run it from bash or Radare2.
The output is always `0xffffc9f4` when I run it from Python.
The output is also different when I run it from bash file.

It is not clearly a problem in C code. But this is about memory placement problem implicitly done by operation system.

Comment: @user253751Thank you for your comment. Yeah, this could be good explanation. I will confirm it later.

Comment: @user253751 I confirmed your theory is right.

I've modified the python code to this following code.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("./vuln",env={})
```

And these commands shows the same results.

```
$python ./exploit.py
0xffffdd34

$ env - ./vuln
0xffffdd34
```

Both process should receive the empty environment variable. And in this case, these program could show the same result. I think your theory was proved.